# how to run at command through chrome serial api

Tags: javascript, serial-port, arraybuffer

i want to run at command at my hardware thorugh crome serial api

I use this Opensource code 
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/servo
this working only for only integer

i want to pass string in the serial port my code is like following

```
 var connectionId = -1;

function setPosition(position) {
  var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(1);
  var uint8View = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  uint8View[0] = '0'.charCodeAt(0) + position;

  chrome.serial.write(connectionId, buffer, function() {});
};
function setTxt(data) {
 // document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = data;
  var bf = str2ab(data)
  chrome.serial.write(connectionId, bf, function() {});
};
function str2ab(str) {
  len = str.length;
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(len*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  return buf;
}
function onRead(readInfo) {
  var uint8View = new Uint8Array(readInfo.data);
 var value1 = String.fromCharCode(uint8View[0])
  var value = uint8View[0] - '0'.charCodeAt(0);
  var rotation = value * 18.0;
 // var dataarr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(readInfo.data));
  //alert(rotation);
  if(uint8View[0])
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML + value1;
  document.getElementById('image').style.webkitTransform =
    'rotateZ(' + rotation + 'deg)';
//  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=uint8View[0];
  // Keep on reading.
  chrome.serial.read(connectionId, 1, onRead);
};
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

function onOpen(openInfo) {
  connectionId = openInfo.connectionId;
  if (connectionId == -1) {
    setStatus('Could not open');
    return;
  }
  setStatus('Connected');

  setPosition(0);
  chrome.serial.read(connectionId, 1, onRead);
};

function setStatus(status) {
  document.getElementById('status').innerText = status;
}

function buildPortPicker(ports) {
  var eligiblePorts = ports.filter(function(port) {
    return !port.match(/[Bb]luetooth/);
  });

  var portPicker = document.getElementById('port-picker');
  eligiblePorts.forEach(function(port) {
    var portOption = document.createElement('option');
    portOption.value = portOption.innerText = port;
    portPicker.appendChild(portOption);
  });

  portPicker.onchange = function() {
    if (connectionId != -1) {
      chrome.serial.close(connectionId, openSelectedPort);
      return;
    }
    openSelectedPort();
  };
}

function openSelectedPort() {
  var portPicker = document.getElementById('port-picker');
  var selectedPort = portPicker.options[portPicker.selectedIndex].value;
  chrome.serial.open(selectedPort, onOpen);
}

onload = function() {
  var tv = document.getElementById('tv');
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(
      {video: true},
      function(stream) {
        tv.classList.add('working');
        document.getElementById('camera-output').src =
            webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
      },
      function() {
        tv.classList.add('broken');
      });

  document.getElementById('position-input').onchange = function() {
    setPosition(parseInt(this.value, 10));
  };
  document.getElementById('txt-input').onchange = function() {

    setTxt(this.value);
   // document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = this.value;
  };
  chrome.serial.getPorts(function(ports) {
    buildPortPicker(ports)
    openSelectedPort();
  });
};
```

string is the passing through serial but this command not run without enter press how to do it any one know

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

need a `\n` at the end of string

example:

```
writeSerial( '#;Bit_Test;*;1;' + '\n' );
```

take a look at this project http://www.dataino.it/help/document_tutorial.php?id=13